# What does enabling notifications on desktop chat opened on Android Chrome do?

Tags: support, chat, google-chrome, android, desktop-notifications

I use the full desktop version of the chat site on Android mobile (when I do use chat on mobile at all). It has the usual option to enable desktop notifications, and I enabled those. Best I can tell, it has no effect at all. The title gets modified when somebody sends me an @ping, but there's no other visual or audible indication at all.

What's going on? Does Chrome on Android lack some feature?